# How to use php variable instead .twig file?

Tags: twig

Is there a possibility to use php variable as template, instead of .twig file ?

I have a big template file, that I want to be able to store to database, for later editing by users. Here is example:

```php
$aTwigdata['TEMPLATE'] = '                      
                
                {% if aGroups|length > 0 %}

                    {% for aGroup in aGroups %}
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="left">
                                <div class="group_id">
                                    <span>{{ aGroup.GroupId }}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item_box_info">
                                    <h4>{{ aGroup.GroupName }}</h4>
                                    <p>                                                     
                                        <span>{{ TEXT_GROUP_LINK }}: {{ aGroup.GroupLink }}</span>
                                        
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
           
           
                            <div class="action_btns">
                                <a href="#" class="action_btn data-idkey="{{ aGroup.IdKey }}">
                                    <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
                                </a>
                                
                                ...
                                
                                <a href="#" class="tooltip action_btn" data-idkey="{{ aGroup.iSliderGroupIdKey }}">
                                    <span class="tooltiptext">{{ ISL_TEXT_GROUP_DELETE }}</span>
                                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>                     
                        </div>

                            {% if  aGroup.items|length > 0 %}
                                <ul class="Group_list">         
                                {% for aItem in  aGroup.items %}
                                
                                    <li> 
                                        <div class="item">
                                            <div class="left">
                                                <div class="slider_img">
                                                    <img src="{{ URL }}{{ aItem.GId }}/{{ aItem.Image }}" alt="{{ aGroup.Title }}">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="info">
                                                    <h4>{{ aItem.Title }}</h4>
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                           
                           
                                            <div class="action_btns">
                                                <a href="#" class="action_btn data-idkey="{{ aGroup.IdKey }}">
                                                    <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
                                                </a>
                                                
                                                
                                                ..
                                                
                                                <a href="#" class="tooltip action_btn" data-idkey="{{ aItem.IdKey }}">
                                                    <span class="tooltiptext">{{ TEXT_GROUP_DELETE }}</span>
                                                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>                     
                                        </div>                                                  
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    </li>
                                    
                                
                                {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            {% else %}
                                <div class="Group_list">                        
                                    <div class="box">
                                        <div class="left">
                                            <div class="info">
                                                <h4>{{ TEXT_ITEMS_NO_ITEMS }}</h4>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            {% endif %} 
                    {% endfor %}
                    
                {% else %}
                        <div class="item_box">
                            <div class="item_box_left">
                                <div class="item_box_info">
                                    <h4>{{ TEXT_GROUP_NO_GROUPS }}</h4>
                                    <p>{{ TEXT_GROUP_NO_GROUPS_CREATE }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>                     
                        </div>
                {% endif %} ';
```

So far I have this:

```php
if (class_exists('\Twig\Environment') && is_readable($sPath.'/templatefile.twig'))
{
    // create twig template object
    $loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader($sPath);
    $twig   = new \Twig\Environment($loader, [
        'autoescape'       => false,
        'cache'            => false,
        'strict_variables' => false,
        'debug'            => false, 
        'auto_reload'      => true,
    ]);
    $aJsonRespond['out'] = $twig->render('templatefile.twig', $aTplData);

// Replace above line with:
// THE ANSWER to use php string variable instead file:


                        $oTpl = $oTwig->createTemplate($aTwigdata['TEMPLATE']);
                        $aJsonRespond['out'] = $oTpl->render($aTplData);

} else {
    // Twig not exists
    $aJsonRespond['out'] = '<br>TWIG is not initialized!';
}
```

Now I am wondering how can I use this variable `$aTwigdata['TEMPLATE']` within twig call, instead of calling file templatefile.twig , is this possible ?